# Convert Unknown Number of Dict Indexes to Individual Dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe, unique

I created a dict `d = {}`, and I loop through web pages and store the data from each page in `d[i]`. The data on each page is about 20 columns and 100 rows of data. When it is finished, I could have any number of indexes. The issue I'm having is that some of the pages are duplicates. So `d[3]` and `d[4]` could be duplicates.

I eventually convert each index to a dataframe like so:

```
   df1 = d[0]
   df1 = pd.DataFrame(df1[0])
```

If I know the number of indexes, I know how to convert them into one dataframe as follows:

```
   dfs = len(d)
   #Union dataframes
   if dfs == 4:
   df1 = d[0]
   df2 = d[1]
   df3 = d[2]
   df4 = d[3]
   df1 = pd.DataFrame(df1[0])
   df2 = pd.DataFrame(df2[0])
   df3 = pd.DataFrame(df3[0])
   df4 = pd.DataFrame(df4[0])
   df = pd.concat([df1,df2,df3,df4])
```

However, I don't always know the number. Is there a way to do this for an unknown number of indexes and to remove the duplicate pages? I was thinking about creating a for loop with a variable object name but I know that's probably not the best way to go about it.

Answer (score 0):

This takes every `i` in `d` and makes a `DataFrame` of `i[0]`, then passes the list of those `DataFrame`s to `pd.concat`

```
df = pd.concat(list(map(pd.DataFrame, (i[0] for i in d.values()))))
```

Comment: I get the following error when I run that code:

`df = pd.concat(list(map(pd.DataFrame, i[0] for i in d.values())))`
                           ^
`SyntaxError: Generator expression must be parenthesized if not sole argument`

Comment: Am I supposed to run this in my loop while pulling data from the web pages, or after I ran that code and the dict with the multiple indexes is created? I ran it afterwards and `df` gives me the equivalent of `d[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

In similar situations, I've gone about this problem in the following way:

```
def convert_dict_to_frame(dict):
  dict_list = []
  frame_list = []
  for key in dict.keys():
    if dict[key] not in dict_list:
      dict_list.append(dict[key])
  for x in dict_list:
    frame_list.append(pd.DataFrame(x))
  df = pd.concat(frame_list)
  return df
```

I'll admit that it might be a slower way of getting it done, but it's worked for me.

Comment: When I use this code, and I look at `df` it contains an index for each column in `d[0]`. I'm not seeing the data from `d[1]`, `d[2]` and so on.

Comment: Hmm. Can you give me a sample of how your dictionary is structured? I'd like to take a more in-depth look at this.